# Where is this space coming from in cat()

Tags: r

If i run:

```
r_2 = 0.89 # (wow that's an impressive R^2)
rmse = 24724.58
cat("R^2: ", r_2, '\n',"RMSE: ", rmse)
```

in the RStudio Console it returns:

```
R^2:  0.89 
 RMSE:  24724.58
```

is it obvious why there's an extra space before `RMSE`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that's due to the `sep` argument of `cat`:

> sep - a character vector of strings to append after each element.

```
cat("R^2: ", r_2, '\n', "RMSE: ", rmse, sep = "")
# R^2: 0.89
# RMSE: 24724.58
```